# Is there any way to redownload games attached to another NNID?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I bought a used 3DS XL off Craigslist and the person had 3 digital copy games on the system when he sold it to me. He said I should be able to redownload at least 2 of them that he was pretty sure of when I reset it and set up my own account on it.

However, since doing the system reset and getting a NNID set up for myself they are not listed in redownload-able software. I contacted Nintendo support via chat line and they said that there was noting that can be done because the games still belong to the previous owner still.

Is there ANY way to get around this?

I have contacted the person I bought it from & they said they would try to find their NNID stuff and I just haven't heard from them yet. They were both great games & really want them back since they were included in the total price I paid for the system & all its stuff that came with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user is attempting to download software that he/she doesn't own a legal license for. As the user learned via their chat with Nintendo support, the software is owned by the purchaser of the games, not the person who currently has the device. As such, it cannot be transferred to a new account.

Answer (score 4):

Since you created a new NNID, you've lost the licenses to those games that were attached to the old NNID. If the seller gets back to you with their NNID information and they give it to you, you may be able to contact Nintendo support with the info and ask them to merge the accounts for you, but it's not guaranteed.